# Securing Apache and PHP-FPM

Tags: apache, security, php

Given

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$1
```

how can one prevent malicious code execution when a fake image is uploaded in a folder which is then called via

```
http://www.foo.bar/uploads/malicious.jpg/fake.php
```

If I understand correctly, the request above will let Apache pass it to PHP-FPM which will execute /uploads/malicious.jpg.

I know I could add an .htaccess file in the uploads folder that removes the ProxyPassMatch, but this is something my customers don't know and they could end up being compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new setting in php-fpm since php 5.3.9, 'security.limit_extensions', that limits which files php-fpm will execute. The default is '.php', so the 'malicious.jpg' would not be executed.